# Print of chart generated using c3js

Tags: jquery, charts

Need a way to take print of the chart generated using c3js.

I tried below code:

```
 var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');        
    //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/c3.css" type="text/css" />');     

    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write($('#chart').html());
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
```

but it gives me improper chart
[enter link description here](http://amit26feb.blogspot.com/2015/08/blog-post.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

printelement JS helped me. Its very simple

[PrintElement](https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQuery.printElement)

Answer (score 0):

In your example the inclusion of the c3.css file is uncommented, why is that? It seems like it's really just the CSS that's missing.

And you should try to call the window.print() when the window you opened finished loading. You could achieve that with calling window.print() in the body's onload event.

```
<body onload="window.print()">
```

Another thing that sometimes helped was a little timeout :), but that's not really a preferred solution.

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() {window.print();}, 2000);">
```

Comment: Using onload and uncommenting c3.css didnt made any difference. Also c3.css is included in bundle config, so i feel it is not required to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css file:

```
@media print {

    .c3 path, .c3 line {    
        fill: none; 
        stroke: #000;
    }
```

Pardon my formatting, this is my first post to stackoverflow.